# Using two way binding to update html in angular app

Tags: angular

When a user logs into my app i want to change text to show their My Account page as opposed to the Login page.

**This is what I have:**

```
<li><a (click)="openLoginForm()">
    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> 
    {{ isLoggedIn ? "My Account" : "Login / Register" }}</a>
</li>
```

**And in my code:**

```
isLoggedIn = false;
ngOnInit() {
//run some checks
isLoggedIn = true;
}
```

While I can see the value changing in the console.log, the actual HTML is not changing.

I have been told this has something to do with two-way binding.

With the ongoing changes with angular, I am not 100% sure how to go about this since ng2 has changed quite dramatically over the last few months.

While I can do this very easily with JQuery, I have made it a mission to only use NG2...

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: How does this display when you load the page? "My Account" or "Login/Register"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a function you need to use **`this`**

Since, the **reference to a variable changes when inside a function**. You need to use **`this.isLoggedIn = true;`**

```
isLoggedIn = false;
ngOnInit() {
  //run some checks
  this.isLoggedIn = true;
}
```

[**Here is a DEMO if the same**](https://plnkr.co/edit/wUfiyX5zjoiHWeKKQ25D?p=preview)

Comment: Hi - yes, typo in my code. I do have this... however it still does not work.